# Click Event in a Dynamically Generated Razor Pages is not Working

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

I was trying to Display some Items in a tree view. Depending On Level of the Node particular set of Button is Displayed. The Data for Display is brought from a table having following Data

```
ID  Name Description Icon ParentId FunctionalityId
1   M1  Top M1  NULL    0   NULL
2   M2  Top M2  NULL    0   NULL
3   M3  Top M3  NULL    0   NULL
4   M4  Top M4  NULL    0   NULL
5   M1m1    M1m1    NULL    1   NULL
6   M1m2    M2m2    NULL    1   NULL
7   M1m3    M1m3    NULL    1   NULL
8   M2m1    M2m1    NULL    2   NULL
9   M2m2    M2m2    NULL    2   NULL
10  M3m1    M3m1    NULL    3   NULL
11  M1m2m1  M1m2m1  NULL    6   1
12  M2m2m2  M1m2m2  NULL    6   2
13  M2m2m3  M2m2m3  NULL    9   3
14  M1m1m1  M2m1m1  NULL    5   4
15  M1m1m2  M2m1m2  NULL    5   5
16  M3m1m1  M3m1m1  NULL    10  6
17  M4m1    M4m1    NULL    4   NULL
18  M4m2    M4m2    NULL    4   NULL
19  M4m1m1  M4m1m1  NULL    17  7
20  M4m1m2  M4m1m2  NULL    17  8
21  M4m1m3  M4m1m3  NULL    17  9
22  M4m2m1  M4m2m1  NULL    18  10
```

Data is loaded into a class
public class MenuItemHierarchy
{

```
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public int? FunctionalityId { get; set; }
        public List<MenuItemHierarchy> Children { get; set; } // Added property for children nodes

        public bool IsLeafNode => Children == null || Children.Count == 0;
        
}
```

I display the Data in side a Razor Pages using a Recursive Function.

```
<h2>Menu Items</h2>
<div>
    @await RecursiveRenderNodes(Model.MenuItems)
</div>




@* Recursive function to render the nodes *@
@functions {
    public async Task<IHtmlContent> RecursiveRenderNodes(List<MenuItemHierarchyDTO> nodes)
    {
        var content = new HtmlContentBuilder();
        if (nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            content.AppendHtml("<ul>");
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                //content.AppendHtml("<div>");
                content.AppendHtml("<li>");
                content.AppendHtml($"<p>{node.Name}</p>");

                if (node.IsLeafNode)
                {
                    // Click to go to appropriate page
                    content.AppendHtml("<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" asp-page=\"Edit\" asp-route-id=\"" + @node.Id + "\">Edit</a> | ");
                    content.AppendHtml("<a  class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" asp-page=\"Delete\" asp-route-id=\"" + @node.Id + "\">Delete</a>");
 
                   }
                else
                {
                    // Click to go to appropriate page
                    content.AppendHtml("<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" asp-page=\"Create\" asp-route-id=\"" + @node.Id + "\">Add New Child</a> | ");
                    content.AppendHtml("<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" asp-page=\"Edit\" asp-route-id=\"" + @node.Id + "\">Edit</a>");
                 }
                if (node.Children != null && node.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    var childrenContent = await RecursiveRenderNodes(node.Children);
                    content.AppendHtml(childrenContent);
                }
                content.AppendHtml("</li>");
                //content.AppendHtml("</div>");
            }
            content.AppendHtml("</ul>");
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Resulting page shows the hierarchy along with the clickable buttons. However the buttons are nonfunctional, ie on click we are not being redirected to the Edit/Delete/Create Page.
The Page Source of the Generated Page is apparently perfect.

```
<h2>Menu Items</h2>
<div>
    <ul><li><p>M1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="1">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="1">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M1m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="5">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="5">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M1m1m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="14">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="14">Delete</a></li><li><p>M1m1m2</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="15">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="15">Delete</a></li></ul></li><li><p>M1m2</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="6">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="6">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M1m2m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="11">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="11">Delete</a></li><li><p>M2m2m2</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="12">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="12">Delete</a></li></ul></li><li><p>M1m3</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="7">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="7">Delete</a></li></ul></li><li><p>M2</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="2">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="2">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M2m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="8">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="8">Delete</a></li><li><p>M2m2</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="9">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="9">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M2m2m3</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="13">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="13">Delete</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><p>M3</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="3">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="3">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M3m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="10">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="10">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M3m1m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="16">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="16">Delete</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><p>M4</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="4">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="4">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M4m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="17">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="17">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M4m1m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="19">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="19">Delete</a></li><li><p>M4m1m2</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="20">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="20">Delete</a></li><li><p>M4m1m3</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="21">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="21">Delete</a></li></ul></li><li><p>M4m2</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Create" asp-route-id="18">Add New Child</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="18">Edit</a><ul><li><p>M4m2m1</p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="22">Edit</a> | <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="22">Delete</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
</div>
```

**===== Solution as suggested by Mike Brind =============**

```
if (node.IsLeafNode)
                {
                    // Display Edit and Delete buttons for leaf nodes
                    content.AppendHtml($"<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" href=\"{Url.Page("./Edit", new { id = node.Id })}\">Edit</a>  ");
                    content.AppendHtml($"<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" href=\"{Url.Page("./Delete", new { id = node.Id })}\">Delete</a>");

                }
                else
                {
                    // Click to go to appropriate page
                    content.AppendHtml($"<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" href=\"{Url.Page("./Create", new { id = node.Id })}\">Create Child Node</a>  ");
                    content.AppendHtml($"<a class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" href=\"{Url.Page("./Edit", new { id = node.Id })}\">Edit</a>");

                }
```

At the hind side I realize my mistake and think I should have used a view component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating tag helpers as raw HTML to be rendered in the browser. That doesn't work because tag helpers are a server-side feature that generate HTML at  runtime to be sent to the browser. Generate HTML anchor elements with `href` attributes instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion It worked. I changed my code which is given at the bottom of my original question.